# telebot missing 1 required positional argument: 'message'

Tags: python-3.x, telebot

i'm trying to make a telegram bot (telebot)
i am having a problem with my code

```
@bot.message_handler(commands=['testes'])
def testes(send_photo,message):
    qr75 = open('qr75.jpg', 'rb')
    bot.send_photo(send_photo.chat.id, qr75)
    bot.send_message(message.chat.id'Hallo')
```

and i got this error

```
TypeError: testes() missing 1 required positional argument: 'message'
```

what should I fix? sorry I'm a beginner

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think there's a little mix up in the function arguments going on.
Here's the documentation on `@bot.message_handler` https://pytba.readthedocs.io/en/latest/sync_version/index.html#telebot.TeleBot.message_handler

> As a parameter to the decorator function, it passes telebot.types.Message object.

Therefore, your function `testes` should expect only one argument - `message`.

I changed your code a bit, now it should work:

```
@bot.message_handler(commands=['testes'])
def testes(message):
    qr75 = open('qr75.jpg', 'rb')
    bot.send_photo(message.chat.id, qr75)
    bot.send_message(message.chat.id, 'Hallo')
```

(also added a comma on the last row)

Hope that helps!